# Finding the average num of patients per day. SQL

Tags: sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'NumOfConsultations'
SELECT consultationDate DISTINCT(*) AS 'NumOfDays'
FROM consultation
SUM('NumOfDays' / 'NumOfCosultations' = 'AveragePatientsPerDay');
```

I am trying to find the average number of consultations per day.  Any tips?

Comment: Can you add the database you are working on? Along with the current output and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you can do this:

```
SELECT 
   AVG(consultationId) AS 'Average Consultations Per Day', 
   COUNT(consultationId) AS 'Total Consultations Per Day'
FROM consultation
GROUP BY CAST(consultationDate AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The average number of consultations per day, as I understand the question, would be:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct consultationDate)
from consultation;
```

If `consultationDate` actually has a time component (in addition to a date), you will need to convert it to a date.  This depends on the database, but something like:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct cast(consultationDate as date))
from consultation;
```

or:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct trunc(consultationDate))
from consultation;
```

or:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct date(consultationDate))
from consultation;
```

would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

select count(*) / count(distinct serv_date) as avg
from Production;